# puppet module not being added to catalog

Tags: linux, puppet

I have a module that builds /etc/passwd on nodes using concat. The puppetmaster is somehow not able to see that I've created the module. When I run 'puppet agent -t' on the client nodes, I see no errors nor is the password file touched.

```
class eeee_passwd {

$eeee_passwd = '/etc/passwd'
  concat  { $eeee_passwd:
  owner => root,
  group => root,
  mode  => '0644',
}

concat::fragment  { 'passwd_root':
  target  =>  $eeee_passwd,
  content =>  'root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash',
  order   =>  01,
}

concat::fragment  { 'passwd_bin':
  target  =>  $eeee_passwd,
  content =>  'bin:x:1:1:bin:/bin:/sbin/nologin',
  order   =>  02,
}

concat::fragment { 'passwd_daemon':
  target  =>  $eeee_passwd,
  content =>  'daemon:x:2:2:daemon:/sbin:/sbin/nologin',
  order   =>  03,
}
```

Comment: So, are you *including* `class eee_passwd`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a module is not sufficient.  You must also instruct the master to add the one or more appropriate classes or resources provided by the module to the node's catalog.  For instance, supposing that you are classifying nodes via node blocks, you might have something like this:

```
node mynode {
  ...
  include 'eeee_passwd'
  ...
}
```

If it were otherwise, then you would have a lot of trouble managing dissimilar nodes via the same master.

Comment: <code>
filebucket { 'main':
  server => 'schmoo.dystopialand.com',
  path   => false,
}

File { backup => 'main' }

hiera_include('classes')

node default {
}
<code>